# Como encontrar todos os lugares onde estão sendo utilizados métodos depreciados no Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, deprecated

Há alguma ferramenta no Netbeans que permita gerar um arquivo, um relatório, um log, ou algo do gênero, para encontrar todos os métodos que estão depreciados em uma Classe ou Projeto?

Tentei encontrar na Internet, e no próprio Stack, porém, só achei algo para o Eclipse, onde eram apresentados junto aos warnings do projeto.

Utilizo o Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: Iria responder mas se você não se importar em traduzir, a resposta está no stackoverflow em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583138/how-do-i-detect-the-deprecated-methods-in-a-program

Comment: Obrigado, talvez tenha sido a forma como pesquisei, dando maior foco em "Netbeans" do que em Java que fez eu não encontrar.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Abra as propriedades do seu projeto, vá até a opção `Compilação` dentro da opção `Construir` na árvore do lado esquerdo. No campo `Opções Adicionais do Compilador` insira `-deprecation`. Depois disso os métodos depreciados serão mostrados como `warning` no `output` do projeto quando compilado.

[image: Imagem]

---

> [`-deprecation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)
>
> Show a description of each use or override of a deprecated member or class.

Em tradução livre:

> Mostra a descrição de cada uso ou sobrecarga de membros ou classes depreciados.